# The difference between customize function and native function in prototype

Tags: javascript

'For In' can traverse Array (value/properties/function).

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.__proto__.con = function(){console.log('from array');}
for(let item in arr){
 console.log(item);
}
```

The result will be:

```
1,2,3,4,con
```

why does native function like 'toString'/'split'  not be printed?
what is the difference?

In my mind, they(`con` and `toString`) all belong to the prototype of Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for...in` statement...

> iterates over all non-Symbol, **enumerable properties** of an object. ([source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in))

However, if you look at the [ECMA specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype), in the item *"Properties of the Array Prototype Object"*, you'll see that:

> The Array prototype object is the intrinsic object %ArrayPrototype%. The Array prototype object is an Array exotic objects and has the internal methods specified for such objects. It has a length property whose initial value is 0 and whose attributes are { [[Writable]]: true, **[[Enumerable]]: false**, [[Configurable]]: false }.

That applies to `concat`, `filter`, `map`, `forEach`, `sort`, `toString` etc...

You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` to check those attributes. For instance:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype, "concat"));
```

Finally, for setting those methods with `{enumerable: false}`, have a look at the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58947130/12273078).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that the method is assigned to the prototype. Properties of any type of object are [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) by default, whether they are assigned to the object's prototype or directly to the object:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 10;
    }
}
let test = new MyClass();     
test.y = 20;
for(let item in test) {console.log(item) } // logs x, y
```

Native methods like `toString` are set to be non-enumerable, for the obvious reason that you don't often want to loop through them. User methods or properties can also be set to be non-enumerable, by using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(test, "z", {value: 42, enumerable: false})
console.log(test.z);           // 42
for(let item in test) {console.log(item)}   // still only x, y
```